# What exactly do i need to write to add the ability for emission maps to this shader

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader

I am trying to understand shaders written with code, The shader that this is for is sprites in a 3D world in unity that react to the 3D lighting and will have emission maps. I will use shader graph later but wanna see how I can add a very basic emission map with code cause I am not that familiar with shaders and am not exactly sure where to write what, I think this will help me understand shaders a bit more.

```
{
    Properties
    {
        [PerRendererData] _MainTex("Sprite Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        [PerRenderData] _EmissionMap("Emission Map", 2D) = "white" {}
        [HDR] _EmissionColor("Color", Color) = (1,1,1)
        _Color("Tint", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        [MaterialToggle] PixelSnap("Pixel snap", Float) = 0
        [HideInInspector] _RendererColor("RendererColor", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        [HideInInspector] _Flip("Flip", Vector) = (1,1,1,1)
        [PerRendererData] _AlphaTex("External Alpha", 2D) = "white" {}
        [PerRendererData] _EnableExternalAlpha("Enable External Alpha", Float) = 0
        _Cutoff("Alpha Cutoff", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
    }

        SubShader
        {
            Tags
        {
            "Queue" = "Transparent"
            "IgnoreProjector" = "True"
            "RenderType" = "Transparent"
            "PreviewType" = "Plane"
            "CanUseSpriteAtlas" = "True"
        }

            Cull Off
            Lighting Off
            ZWrite Off
            Blend One OneMinusSrcAlpha

            CGPROGRAM
    #pragma surface surf Lambert vertex:vert alphatest:_Cutoff addshadow nofog nolightmap nodynlightmap keepalpha noinstancing
    #pragma multi_compile_local _ PIXELSNAP_ON
    #pragma multi_compile _ ETC1_EXTERNAL_ALPHA
    #include "UnitySprites.cginc"

            struct Input
        {
            float2 uv_MainTex;
            fixed4 color;
        };

        void vert(inout appdata_full v, out Input o)
        {
            v.vertex = UnityFlipSprite(v.vertex, _Flip);

    #if defined(PIXELSNAP_ON)
            v.vertex = UnityPixelSnap(v.vertex);
    #endif

            UNITY_INITIALIZE_OUTPUT(Input, o);
            o.color = v.color * _Color * _RendererColor;
        }

        void surf(Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o)
        {
            fixed4 c = SampleSpriteTexture(IN.uv_MainTex) * IN.color;
            o.Albedo = c.rgb * c.a;
            o.Alpha = c.a;
            //o.Emission = 
        }
        ENDCG
        }

            Fallback "Transparent/VertexLit"
}
```

This is my current code I would like to know what I exactly need to write where cause I keep having problems or errors I hope the question can be answered on here.